# Powershell - Trying to export to csv but only last record gets picked up

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to export an object to a CSV file but only the last sheet gets saved - any idea why?

```
$rangeAddr=$startCell_appname + ":" + $endCell_appname
$sh.Range($rangeAddr).Value2 |
  foreach {
    $apps = "" | Select appname,location,lob,os
    $apps.appname = $_ 
    $apps.location = ""   
    $apps.lob = $sh.Name
    $apps.os = "Windows 7"
    $apps
   } | Export-csv "apps.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It looks like each iteration through the foreach loop is overwriting the data stored by the previous iteration, and only the last iteration is getting to the file.

Comment: How can I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and don't want to stop it from overwriting.
The foreach loop is creating a series of objects, reusing the same variable.
At the end of the loop each completed object is output to the pipeline.
You just need to pick them up from there.

```
clear all

$before = @(get-process excel | %{$_.Id})
$excel=new-object -com excel.application
$excelId = get-process excel | %{$_.Id} | ?{$before -notcontains $_}
$wb=$excel.workbooks.open("c:\b7.xlsx")

$(for ($i=3; $i -le $wb.sheets.count; $i++){

    $sh=$wb.Sheets.Item($i)
    $startCell_appname = $sh.cells.item(1,2).EntireColumn.find("Application Name").Address()
    $startCell_appname = [regex]::replace($startCell_appname, '(\$\w+\$)(\d+)', {param($m) $m.groups[1].value + ([int]$m.groups[2].value+1)})    

    $endCell_appname = $sh.cells.item(1,2).EntireColumn.find("").Address()
    $endCell_appname = [regex]::replace($endCell_appname, '(\$\w+\$)(\d+)', {param($m) $m.groups[1].value + ([int]$m.groups[2].value-1)})

    # pull data
    $rangeAddr=$startCell_appname + ":" + $endCell_appname
    $sh.Range($rangeAddr).Value2 |
      foreach {
        $apps = "" | Select appname,location,lob,os
        $apps.appname = $_ 
        $apps.location = ""   
        $apps.lob = $sh.Name
        $apps.os = "Windows 7"
        $apps
       } 
}) | Export-csv "apps.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# kill excel process
Stop-Process -Id $excelId -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of powershell are you using? For V3 and V4 use `-append` :

```
Export-csv "apps.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```